# Local JSON data as global variable in seperate .js file?

Tags: javascript, json

I have about one week of experience with javascript and jquery, and am playing around with an offline multiple-choice/flashcard app with a fixed deck. Would it be a bad idea to simply add "cards = " to the beginning of what would otherwise be a .json file and simply include it as another .js in my main page, instead of parsing it?

Comment: Since it represents data, and not code, it is a good idea to keep it separate from your code. 

Since the application is offline, it makes no sense to store it on a server, so a separate JavaScript file will work.

Avoiding the parsing will only slightly improve your performance overall, even if you repeatedly had the application re-parse it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: @Philip your link to Jon Skeet's blog is broken

Comment: Thank you Joeppie, exactly what I was thinking.